# Call PHP File after JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF and I want my form input text to be available in PDF format. So when I type something in input fields, and I press export to PDF, I want it to be there. So here is how I planned my solution. The problem appears when I call the PHP with POST from HTML because It does not update the input values. It just sends the blank ones. I need to change that so it updates them.

1) Fill in the input fields with text
2) Click Export to PDF
3) Use JQuery to change the HTML with input values
4) Call the PHP file (`$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('index.php'));`

I tried using AJAX for this but it doesn't work. I DON'T need to send ANY data to the PHP File. I just need to call if after the JQuery changed the HTML.

Here's my PHP File:

```
<?php
require_once 'autoload.inc.php';
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('index.php'));
// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render('doc.pdf');

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

And my JQUERY File

```
function ajax() {
    alert('in');
$.ajax({
    url: 'jobsheet.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success:function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

If you have any other solution for this, please let me know!

Comment: If you are wanting to change something in the output of the PDF generation then you do need to send something, otherwise it will only use previously supplied information. You cannot submit from client to server without an ajax call or a form submit, at least i've never been aware of a way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect Dompdf to display your content but also don't send it any data? You might need to clarify that point. Are you saying you want to render the browser-modified HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your technique.

First, Dompdf (as of 0.6.1) does not parse PHP so you will need to pre-parse that before passing it off to dompdf. You can use output buffering for that:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'index.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();

require_once 'autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

Second, if all you want to do is display the results why use AJAX at all? It requires significantly more work to fetch and display the PDF document this way when you could simply use a form post. If you have a particular need for using AJAX you should specify.